# Sort nodes in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XSL variable `matchedNodes` which holds XML data. Which means

```
   <xsl:copy-of select="$matchedNodes"/>
```

will produce an XML like this

```
    <home name="f">
  <standardpage>
    <id text="a1"></id>
  </standardpage>
  <searfchpage>
    <id text="a2"></id>
  </searfchpage>
  <searfchpage>
    <id text="a3"></id>
  </searfchpage>
</home>
```

I want to sort this XML so that `searfchpage` nodes always comes first..Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try mine and see if its the one you wanted.

Comment: @HashCoder I have updated my question a little bit for clarification. As i am not an expert in XSLT i am facing some problems in using your question ,like I am unable to decide where to input my XSL variable matchedNodes  in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple ordering (move `<searfchpage>` to the top, keep the rest of the children in orignal order):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="home">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="searfchpage" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::searfchpage)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

complex ordering (lets you define any arbitrary order, either dynamically via a param or statically via a hard-coded string):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="sortOrder" select="'searfchpage,standardpage,otherpage'" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="home">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(
          substring-before(concat($sortOrder, ',', name()), name())
        )" />
      <xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't completely get the first one itself..The XML i showed above is in an xsl variable..can you please tell me how i could pass this variable to this function?

Comment: What do you mean by *"The XML is in an `<xsl:variable>`"*? Is it a string? A result tree fragment? A node set? -- It's best if you add to your question the bit of code that sets the variable.

Comment: Yeah, that's a result tree fragment. You can't easily sort that. I think there is enough indication that your entire approach might be wrong. You can try `<xsl:apply-templates select="$matchedNodes"/>` instead of the `<xsl:copy-of>`, but it's impossible to say without knowing what `$matchedNodes` actually contains.

Comment: $matchedNodes contains the XML i had shown in my question..that's it..Am i missing anything?

Comment: As I said, without seeing the input XML and the workflow you apply to it I'm forced to guess. My best guess is the apply-templates suggestion in the comment above. To give you a definitive answer I would need to see more of your code. If possible, cut it down to the simplest example that correctly demonstrates your situation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40715/discussion-between-aks-and-tomalak)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**Input:**

```
<home name="f">
  <standardpage>
    <id text="a1"></id>
  </standardpage>
  <searfchpage>
    <id text="a2"></id>
  </searfchpage>
  <searfchpage>
    <id text="a3"></id>
  </searfchpage>
</home>
```

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>

       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<home name="f">
   <searfchpage>
      <id text="a2"/>
   </searfchpage>
   <searfchpage>
      <id text="a3"/>
   </searfchpage>
   <standardpage>
      <id text="a1"/>
   </standardpage>
</home>
```