# How to sort XML nodes by ID values using XSLT?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xmlstarlet

I have a large xml file with a lot of row nodes. I want to sort it by each row's id value.

So this would be an example input:

```
<database>
  <table>
    <row>
      <id>10</id>
      <foo>bar</foo>
    </row>
    <row>
      <id>5</id>
      <foo>poit</foo>
    </row>
    <row>
      <id>1</id>
      <foo>narf</foo>
    </row>
  </table>
</database>
```

and this the expected output:

```
<database>
  <table>
    <row>
      <id>1</id>
      <foo>narf</foo>
    </row>
    <row>
      <id>5</id>
      <foo>poit</foo>
    </row>
    <row>
      <id>10</id>
      <foo>bar</foo>
    </row>
  </table>
</database>
```

How can I achieve that? I have `xmlstarlet` at my disposal. It features a [transform](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s02.html) and appearantly I can provide a xslt stylecheet in a xsl file.

I haven't worked with xslt before and am unsure how to proceed.

I have found [some related sorting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829322/sort-nodes-in-xml-using-xslt) providing some XSLT examples, yet I could not get them working in my use case.

My current `sort.xslt` (Note: I don't know what I am doing) looks like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
    <xsl:sort select="row()"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
    <xsl:sort select="id()"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yet it fails:

```
$ xmlstarlet tr sort.xsl example.xml 
Invalid number of arguments
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
Invalid number of arguments
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
Invalid number of arguments
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
<database>
  <table/>
</database>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about xmlstarlet, but I can say that your XSLT should really look like this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
                <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note how you do not need `()` after element names in your XSLT.

See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy1b

(I also note the tag `xmlstarlet` only has 20 followers. You might want to try out some other tools instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info for some help. xsltproc, perhaps?)

Comment: xmlstarlet worked fine: `xmlstarlet tr sort.xsl example.xml | xmlstarlet fo -` ;) And thank you, this was the kickstart I needed.

Comment: Sidenote: xmlstarlet wants this to be version 1.0 for a larger file. Seems to be working nontheless.

Comment: My stylesheet was actually a version of "1.0" one, I just just forgot to change the version number. If a XSLT 1.0 process is given a stylesheet with version "2.0" then it runs in "forward compatibility" mode and will just ignore any xsl instructions it doesn't recognise.